# cant understand python iterator behavior on file object

Tags: python, file, csv, iterator

I am having a problem in understanding a recent phenomenon that broke our code in production. This piece of code

1. reads a csv file from S3 bucket
2. checks if there  is data in file (other than header)
3. If there is data, iterates over the file and does some processing.

```
        with self.s3.get_stream(bucket=self.import_bucket, key_name=self.in_file, mode="rb") as file_obj:
            # Check file for any amount data, return false if there is no Data
            if not self.check_file_for_data(file_obj):
                return False
            my_producer = iter(self.line_producer(file_obj))
            self.header = next(my_producer)
```

```
def check_file_for_data(self, file_obj):
    try:
        next(islice(file_obj, 1, 2))
    except StopIteration:
        # File has no Data other than column names.
        return False
    except Exception as e:
        # unknown problem caused in reading file.
        self.log.error("Error in reading file: {0} for post processing. error message: {1}".format(self.in_file, e))
    else:
        # File has readable data other than Column names.
        return True
```

```
def line_producer(self, file_obj):
    # Added recently to solve this problem, but was working without this, till dec
    file_obj.seek(0)
    self.log.info("LINE PRODUCTION : Started")
    csv_reader_obj = csv.reader(file_obj)
    header = next(csv_reader_obj)
    yield header
    for index, row in enumerate(csv_reader_obj, 1):
        while self.topic_queue.qsize() > 20000:
            pass
        packet = ([index, row, header])
        try:
            # Block at most for 500 sec till an Empty slot is found
            self.topic_queue.put(obj=packet, block=True, timeout= 500)
        except Exception as e:
            self.log.info("LINE PRODUCTION : FAILED")
            type_, value_, traceback_ = sys.exc_info()
            self.log.exception("traceback :{} ||type: {} ||value: {}".format(traceback.extract_tb(traceback_),
                                                                             type_,
                                                                             value_))
            raise ValueError("PROBLEM IN LOADING PACKET TO TASK QUEUE. "
                             "\n  \t PACKET -> {} \n  \t INDEX -> {}".format(packet, index))
        if index % 100000 == 0:
            self.log.info("produced -> {}".format(index))
    self.log.info("LINE PRODUCTION : FINISHED")
    yield index
```

This is working well until December. But started to break recently. After debuggin, what I have understood was.

```
self.header = next(my_producer)
```

this line is returning 2nd line in the file instead of Header. I have to reset the object to get the header like this.

```
    file_obj.seek(0)
```

can any of you please let me know if there is something that I doing wrong here. Also why only break now??

Comment: Unrelated, but there should be no need to call `iter` on the generator function `line_producer`; `next` works just fine without it.

Comment: thanks tobias_k, I will try that and comment back.

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems that `check_file_for_data` always consumes two lines from the file when you do

```
next(islice(file_obj, 1, 2))
```

One line is skipped and the next returned.

I don't really see how your snippet could have ever worked without seeking back to the start of the file in `line_producer`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Yes, what I was wondering too. 
 I taught:
'    csv_reader_obj = csv.reader(file_obj)
      header = next(csv_reader_obj) '
csv_reader_obj is pointed at the initial position of file_obj.

Comment: Understandable, but `csv.reader` does actually not seek, it just starts parsing at whichever position the file object happens to be.

Comment: I am really shocked, how was this even working for these many days. Now I cant sleep without understanding this.